# Found in blood sample - what is it? Hopefully not a nemotode-

Tags: microbiology, hematology, parasitology

After examining someone's blood - through microscope - I found these. There were some more that were not photographed. Could someone please inform me on what these are? Maybe abiotic material on the slide? Hoping that they are not Microfilariae. #3 threw me in a loop.

[image: Something in blood sample[![][1][1]]
[image: Something in blood sample 2]
[image: Something in blood sample 3]

Comment: If you still have blood in the collection vial, I'd smear another slide that I cleaned assiduously. Also, staining would help.

Comment: A scale bar could also help quite a bit.
I second the staining, as that'd really make help make sense of what we're looking at.
Do you have any other clues about this person that could tell us what we're seeing? e.g. recent travel, exposure to anything, any symptoms etc.

Comment: The technical term is gunk. Slide 3 is the giveaway.